# After Insert Trigger on joomla database gives an error1172

Tags: mysql, triggers, joomla3.0

I made AFTER INSERT Trigger on joomla database (table _users) which after registration copies user_id and name to another table.

Everything works fine until someone during registration enters a name that already exists Otherwise the column name is not the primary one or unique. I get an error:

```
Save failed with the following error: Result consisted of more than one row
```

My trigger looks like this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE `new_user` integer;
DECLARE `new_name` VARCHAR(400);
SELECT `id`
INTO `new_user`
FROM `eio3k_users`
WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
SELECT `name`
INTO `new_name`
FROM `eio3k_users`
WHERE `name` = NEW.name;
INSERT INTO `eio3k_point_system`(`user_id`, `name` ) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name);

END
```

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Looks like `NEW.name` value has more than one row corresponding to it. You need to use `LIMIT 1` in the `SELECT name INTO new_name ...` query

Comment: Why are you fetching data using select query? Is new_user not equals to New.id ? name fetched using select query is not equal to New.name? Also provide a insert query of registration.

Comment: I can't help thinking you should be checking for duplicates before you get to this stage.

Comment: Thanks @Madhur Bhaiya. Solved with LIMIT 1